# Redis: Multiple unique keys versus bucketing through Hash

Tags: redis

I have total six type of keys, say a,b,..,f each having around a million subkeys, like a1,a2,...a99999(different in each bucket). What is the faster way to access?

1. Having separate keys by combining bucket name and key like: a_a1,b_b1 etc.
2. Use hash for 6 keys to have buckets and then have 1 million keys in each?

I search stack-overflow and couldn't find such comparison when I have few buckets with huge number of keys!

**Edit1:** Every key and value is string only at maximum 100 characters. I would access it using Jedis library of Java making transactions

Comment: What kind of data do you need to store? How do you need to access it?

Comment: Every key and value is string only at maximum 100 characters. I would access it using Jedis library of Java making transactions. I guess I would use HGET or GET inside the transaction pipe depending what I chose here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question remind me [this](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value) article. It doesn't contains performance benchmarks but seems like your second case (with buckets of keys) will have appropriate performance and small memory footprint.